# How to run php code from an application hosted on Marklogic Server?

Tags: php, xquery, marklogic

I have created a HTTP Server on Marklogic to run my application.  Now my application has a xqy page. Form that xqy page I want to call a page which is written in PHP. How can I execute PHP page from Marklogic?  I have also installed Wamp Server for PHP on my machine. From within the Wamp server that PHP code executes but I want to run that php script from my application which is hosted on Marklogic.

Answer (score 0):

Make an http request via xdmp:http-request().

Answer (score 0):

I think Eric must mean [`xdmp:http-get()`](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3ahttp-get).